# orderby parameter not working in custom query

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I have a really strange issue for a site I'm updating...

All I want to do, is have it so that the posts come in descending order instead of random.  I have the following code, but when you change it from "rand" to "desc" it just defaults to pull in the posts in "asc" order.  I have no idea why. In addition, if you change "orderby" to "order" it just defaults to ascending order... I've done a search through the theme to see where that's happening but there's no place at all where that's listed... can someone please steer me in the right direction?

```
 <?php

 $args= array(
 'post_type' => 'waiting-families',
'orderby' => 'rand'

);

 // The Query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



 // The Loop
 if (have_posts() ):

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id,      'thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft','style' => 'width: 150px;height: 150px;padding: 3px;     background: #f0f0f0; border: 1px solid #65C8C6;')); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php my_excerpt(55); ?>

        <p class="postmetadata">
            <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>
        </p>
   </div>

  <?php endwhile; 
else: echo '<p style="text-align: center; font-size:20px; font-weight: 700; color:         #65c8c6;">More Families to Come.</p>';
 endif;
   ?>


   <?php // Reset Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: It looks correct, what happens if you change your `IF` statement to `if($the_query->have_posts()) :` ? Hard to tell what the problem is on this code, you'll mostly end up with guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderby` does not accept the values `ASC` or `DESC`. These are acceptable values for the parameter `order`. Changing `'orderby' => 'rand'` to `'order' => 'ASC'` should be sufficient and should by rule work

As already pointed out,

```
if (have_posts() ):
```

should be

```
if ($the_query->have_posts() ):
```

Apart from that little discrepancy, you code have to work

It case this does not solve your problem, look in your functions.php for any instance of `pre_get_posts`. The reason for my thinking is, `pre_get_posts` does not only alter the main query, but also all instances of `WP_Query`. You **have to** include the conditional tag `is_main_query()` to target the main query only, otherwise `pre_get_posts` will interfere with instances of `WP_Query`

For additional resources:

- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: Sorry for the tardy reply, yes this fixed that issue!